# If a report uses a stored procedure that takes a long time to run, how do I prevent MS Access from constantly re-running it during development?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a form that calls a report using no input parms. The report gets its result from a complex stored procedure that takes 10-15 seconds to run. The problem is that during development, Access seems to re-run the SP for every little thing. Obviously it will run it when I click the drop-down for the Control Source of a textbox because it needs to know the SP's output field names, but it also re-runs when I switch from report view to layout view or layout view to design view, etc. I'm sure that someone else has found this annoying at some point, so is there anything that can be done here to alleviate this?

Comment: Where/How is it being run?  Sounds like an On Change event is firing it or something.

Comment: You could certainly cache the results by using a snapshot-type recordset and manually assigning the recordset wherever the query is used. Without more details, I unfortunately can't be more specific

Comment: @JohnnyBones I started with a blank report and only put some textboxes/labels on it, set the record source, and assigned the values for the textboxes via the Control Source. I haven't written any custom VBA for this report.

Comment: @ErikA how do I cache results?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the stored procedure is run in a Pass-Through query which is the record source of the report, this is what I do:

Create a local table with the output of the SP, e.g.

```
SELECT * INTO LocalTempTable FROM MyPassThroughQuery
```

Do this as often as the SP changes (e.g. you add new columns).

Use the local table as record source, change the record source to the Pass-Through query before deployment (or if the report is "done").

Comment: This is similar to what I ended up doing. I just made a copy of my SP and made it return dummy data with the same output field names as the real SP.